# How to save and restore value of ON_ERROR_STOP?

Tags: postgresql, psql

> Is there a way to save, temporarily change, and then restore the value of the `psql` `ON_ERROR_STOP` variable?

Basically, I'd like to have the "moral equivalent" of the following in a `psql` script:

```
save_on_error_stop=ON_ERROR_STOP

\unset ON_ERROR_STOP
ALTER TABLE foo DROP COLUMN bar;  -- (for example)
\set ON_ERROR_STOP save_on_error_stop

ALTER TABLE foo ADD COLUMN bar;
```

The point being that the `'\set'` command at the end won't actually set `ON_ERROR_STOP` unless it was set before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to do this in a single `psql` session. According to the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-VARIABLES), one can use `\set` command on it's own to list all `psql` variables.

One can memorize the setting in shell, but this makes the whole thing useless, as it is much more simple just to execute the desired set of queries enforcing the desired `ON_ERROR_STOP` value.

Another alternative is to write an anonymous code block and `DO` some extra logic to detect, whether column needs to be dropped before adding it.

BTW, What is the purpose of dropping and adding column straight after?

---

If it is only to make sure no such column exists, how bout this [`DO`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-do.html) block:

```sql
DO $$
BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.columns
     WHERE table_schema='public' AND table_name='foo'
       AND column_name='bar')
THEN
    EXECUTE format('ALTER TABLE %I.%I ADD %I text',
                   'public','foo','bar');
END IF;
END; $$;
```

You can also create a function if you tend to do such check quite often.

Comment: I want to avoid only the `column already exists` error on the `ADD COLUMN`, but bracketing this command with an `\unset`-`\set` pair would have silenced *every* non-fatal error, which is too much.  The approach I posted avoids the `column already exists` error somewhat more selectively.  It's not perfect: it relies on the implicit assumption that the `DROP COLUMN` line either succeeds, or fails with a `column does not exist` error, or fails due to a condition that would have also caused the `ADD COLUMN` to fail. ...

Comment: ...  These cases almost certainly do not cover all the possibilities, but they cover the most common situations that my code will face, by far.