# How to suspend PostgreSQL's ON_ERROR_STOP for just part of a psql script?

Tags: postgresql, psql, postgresql-9.6

I'm maintaining a `psql` script which I usually want to immediately abort with a non-zero exit code when any part of it fails.

Thus I'm considering to either place

```
\set ON_ERROR_STOP on
```

at the beginning, or to instruct users to run the script with

```sh
 psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=on -f my_script.sql
```

However, there is a part of the script that deliberately fails (and gets rolled back). As the script is for education and demonstration purposes, and as that part demonstrates a CONSTRAINT actually working as it should (by making a subsequent constraint-violating INSERT fail), I can't really "fix" that part to not fail, so the accepted answer from [How to save and restore value of ON_ERROR_STOP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14730762/how-to-save-and-restore-value-of-on-error-stop) doesn't solve my problem.

Thus, I'd like to disable `ON_ERROR_STOP` before that part and restore the setting after the part. If I know that `ON_ERROR_STOP` is enabled in general, this is easy:

```
\set ON_ERROR_STOP off
BEGIN;
-- [ part of the script that purposfully fails ]
ROLLBACK;
\set ON_ERROR_STOP on
```

or

```
\unset ON_ERROR_STOP
BEGIN;
-- [ part of the script that purposefully fails ]
ROLLBACK;
\set ON_ERROR_STOP on
```

However, this blindly (re-)enables `ON_ERROR_STOP`, whether it was enabled before or not.

```
\set previous_ON_ERROR_STOP :ON_ERROR_STOP
\unset ON_ERROR_STOP
BEGIN;
-- [ part of the script that purposefully fails ]
ROLLBACK;
\set ON_ERROR_STOP :previous_ON_ERROR_STOP
```

works if `ON_ERROR_STOP` has previously been explicitly disabled (e.g., set to `off`) but fails if it was unset (and thus just implicitly disabled).

I'd like the script to remain backwards compatible to PostgreSQL 9.x, so I can't yet use the `\if` meta commands introduced in PostgreSQL 10.

Comment: `ON_ERROR_STOP` being empty by default is only true with psql version < 10. With 10 or newer, it would be evaluated as `off`. That doesn't help with 9.x though but the point is you wouldn't need an `\if` test anyway if you targeted PG10, and the answer you linked to is obsolete with that version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can do that.

What you could do, however, is to use a PL/pgSQL block to run the statement and catch and report the error, somewhat like this:

```
DO
$$BEGIN
   INSERT INTO mytab VALUES (...);
EXCEPTION
   WHEN integrity_constraint_violation THEN
      RAISE NOTICE 'Caught error: %', SQLERRM;
END;$$;
```

That will report the error, but it won't cause `psql` to stop.

Answer (score 0):

```
\set CACHE_ON_ERROR_STOP :ON_ERROR_STOP

SELECT CASE 
  WHEN :'CACHE_ON_ERROR_STOP' = ':CACHE_ON_ERROR_STOP' THEN 'off'
  WHEN :'CACHE_ON_ERROR_STOP'::BOOLEAN is true THEN 'on'
  ELSE 'off'
END::boolean AS CACHE_ON_ERROR_STOP
\gset

\set ON_ERROR_STOP off

-- your code here

\set ON_ERROR_STOP :CACHE_ON_ERROR_STOP
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer a bit? E.g., what's the semantic difference between `:'CACHE_ON_ERROR_STOP'` (colon before the quote) and `':CACHE_ON_ERROR_STOP'` (colon inside the quoted text) and what's the purpose of comparing them with `=`? (I suspect it has to do with the case that the setting might not be set at all?)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).